# Submenu showing when hovering in its area css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am bit problem with my submenu.It should show when hovering on parent menu `li`
But it also showing when mouse is hovering on its area.Let's see with an image.

Below is the first screenshot : it works properly

And below is the second one.it show submenu when hovering on a list item on submenu

now get introduced with html codes

```
<nav class="header-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Blog Styles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Image Post</a></li>
                <li><a href="">audio post</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Level 1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

### And css

```
nav.header-navigation ul > li > ul{
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: auto;
    top: 21px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 15px 17px 13px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
    -o-transform: translateY(10px);
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;

}
nav.header-navigation > ul > li:hover > ul{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
}
nav.header-navigation > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
}
```

Comment: its working fine here? the hover showing on <a href="">Blog Styles</a>

Comment: Yes all working fine..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you are experiencing troubles when hovering outside the link "Blog Styles" As in same y-coordinate but different x-coordinate. That is because the element "li" currently has the width of your screen and therefore you can hover on any x-coordinate as long as your y-coordinate is the same.

You can solve this problem by giving your "li" element a width which will specify the hovering area to a smaller location. For example -

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class = "test">
        <a href="">Blog Styles</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Image Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="">audio post</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Level 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Same css but adding the class ".test" with a width -

```
.test {
   width: 100px;
}
```

Will set the width of the class to a 100 px which will only let you hover within the lists area.